# Why does Make not complain when a target directory is a file instead?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

It appears if I do

```
touch output
```

and then run `make` with the following Makefile

```
output/:
    mkdir $@
```

I get

```
make: 'output' is up to date.
```

despite the fact that `output` is a file, and hence `output/` is not a directory that exists.

Why doesn't Make complain about this, or try to run the recipe for the target directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug that was fixed sometime **after version 3.81**, because this doesn't occur in more recent versions, like 4.2.1:

```
mkdir output
mkdir: cannot create directory 'output': File exists
```

In particular this means that this bug is still encountered in the wild on Mac OS X, since Apple isn't moving on from old versions of GNU software.

Hence for portability you need to protect against this in your makefiles.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand (not 100% sure) this is not really a bug, it is a feature. make 3.81 considers that `target` and `target/` are the same while make 4.2.1 considers that they are different targets. As a consequence make 3.81 does not try to redo `output` while make 4.2.1 does and fails because the file `output` prevents the creation of a directory with the same name.

Comment: Pretty sure it's got to be a bug to consider them the same target considering (a) the newer behavior is to do so, (b) it makes more sense when there's a trailing slash, and (c) I'm not aware of any other situations where different paths for the same file are treated as being the same.